# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, nodejs, heroku

Tengo una app donde el backend se encuentra desplegado en un servidor heroku y me sale este error en el log de dicho server al intentar enviar un email desde el frontend (en el frontend me aparece el error 502).

Route

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')


router.post('/send-email', async (req, res)=>{
    const {name, email, subject, message} = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    contentHTML = `
        <h1>Información de usuario</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Nombre: ${name}</li>
            <li>Email: ${email}</li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
        ${message}
        </p>
    `
    let transporter= nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.enzosantilli.com.ar',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'enzosantilli@enzosantilli.com.ar',
            pass: `${process.env.PASSWORD}`
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "'Enzo Santilli Server' <enzosantilli@enzosantilli.com.ar>",
        to: 'enzo.santilli16@gmail.com',
        subject: `${subject}`,
        html: contentHTML
    });
    transporter.sendMail(info, (error, data)=>{
        if (error){
            res.status(500).send(error.message)
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent', info.messageId);
            res.status(200).json(req.body)
        }
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Creo que se debe a que la petición se tarda más de 30 segundos en realizarse, pero no se como solucionarlo. Ya intenté poner los async y los await correspondientes pero no funciona.

Comment: No es por falta de `async` o `await`, es porque cuando trabajas con Promesas usando `async / await`, debes usar bloques `try ... catch`, de lo contrario, si la Promesa es rechazada saltará una **excepción de rechazo de Promesa no manejada** (`Unhandled Promise Rejection`). Recuerda, si usas `async / await` con Promesas, debes usar `try ... catch`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json())


app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get('port')}`)
});
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta a tu propia pregunta? Si ese fuera el caso, te invito a leer [answer], responder sólo con código sin mayor explicación se considera de baja calidad. Por otro lado, si esto no es una respuesta, entonces debes eliminarla, este espacio es sólo para respuestas a tu pregunta, si deseas añadir algo a tu pregunta hazlo editando la misma. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por el consejo, soy nuevo en la plataforma, se aprecia mucho!